# JavaScript. Потеря значения переменной, связанной с полем формы после изменения этого поля другим скриптом

Tags: javascript

Простая ситуация - на одной HTML-странице работают два JS-скрипта и обрабатывают одно общее поле формы.
После записи значения в поле одним скриптом, переменная в другом скрипте, содержащая ссылку на это поле становится `not defined`.

Почему? Нормальное ли такое поведение, и как "стандартно" в данном случае можно не терять значение и связь с HTML-элементом?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="loc-value" value="123" />
```

**1-й JS-скрипт:**

```
// использует значение поля "loc-value"
let loc_value = document.getElementById("loc-value").value; // в глобальной области видимости 
...
```

**2-й JS-скрипт:**

```
// меняет значение в поле "loc-value" после прочтения 1-м скриптом 
document.getElementById('loc-value').value = '987';
...
```

После записи значения в поле переменная 1-го скрипта становится необъявленной. Область видимости не является причиной. Скрипты работают независимо друг от друга.

Comment: "переменная 1-го скрипта становится необъявленной" - Как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Через отладчик браузера - ошибка в консоли.

Comment: Что значит эта фраза? Что Вы сделали и что получили?

Comment: "два JS-скрипта и обрабатывают одно общее поле" -- такие решения вообще приводят к проблемам, у вас частный случай

Comment: 1-й скрипт прочитал поле в `loc_value` и использует его значение без изменений самого поля и переменной. 2-й скрипт изменил значение поля. После этого 1-й скрипт счёл `loc_value` необъявленным и выдал соответствующую ошибку в консоль браузера.

Comment: Какую "соответствующую ошибку"?

Comment: `deps.js:116 Uncaught ReferenceError: loc_value is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выполнение первого скрипта значение `loc_value` становится 123

После выполнение второго скрипта значение `loc_value` остается 123

Ошибка `not defined` нужно искать не в этих строчках

Чтоб обновить loc_value до текущего значения можно сделать функцию

```
function updateValue(){
  loc_value = document.getElementById("loc-value").value;
}
```

и вызвать её после второго скрипта

Но ошибка `not defined` как раз может быть связана с областью видимости что переменная не определена (не значение)

Тест пример
https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/OJNRmWb

Чтоб найти ошибку нужно больше данных

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Естественно, что по тексту ошибки в первую очередь была проверена область видимости  переменной. Однако, вместе с этой переменной есть ещё одна - сопутствующая ей, т.е. обе переменные объявлены рядом - в одной области и в коде используются везде строго вместе для сравнения значений друг друга. Одна из переменных остаётся "видна" после работы второго скрипта, а другая становится необъявленной. В связи с этим и предположение, что после изменения поля вторым скриптом ссылка на переменную в первом скрипте удалена браузером. Возможно, такое поведение браузера предусмотрено...

Comment: "Возможно, такое поведение браузера предусмотрено" - невозможно.

Comment: Стоп-стоп. После выполнения второго скрипта значение все-таки меняется на "987".

Comment: Нашли ошибку? Напишите апдейт

Answer (score -1):

Навскидку решено простым перечитыванием поля непосредственно перед применением этого значения.

```
loc_value = document.getElementById("loc-value").value; // обновление переменной
```

Comment: А этот способ и напрашивался - обновление данных, который ни чем в сущности не отличается от приведенного ответа @Greg--